# Only select outer elements of first layer for each accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look at my example below. There are some accordions.
If you open them, you will see a red line at the top on some of them.

I need the red line on each accordion, but I am not allowed to change/add classnames by changing the HTML manually. Because this code is generated by my application.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Eddcapone/4oup9wsb/3/)

```js
jQuery(".panel-heading").addClass("accordion");
jQuery(".list-group").addClass("accordion-panel");

jQuery(".outer").find(".widget-static-block:first").addClass("red");

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.accordion-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo" class="outer">
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">AAA</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 1
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 2
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 3
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">BBB</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum A
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum B
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum C
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bar" class="outer">
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">CCC</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 10
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 20
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 30
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">DDD</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum AA
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum BB
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum CC
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: isn't it just `jQuery(".outer").find("> .widget-static-block").addClass("red")`? or you can use children as the answer mentions

Comment: @Huangism, but it does not contain your solution.

Comment: @Huangism, yes but your solution is also a possible solution.

Comment: I would prefer the children answer over the updated css selector

Comment: @Huangism, ok, but I think it is always interesting to see all kind of different solutions which work. You can write in your answer that we should rather use the "children" solution.

Comment: I have commented on the checked answer asking to add the selector as an answer, it would be up to that person to add it. It would be easier to find for future readers if it is in one checked marked answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/):

`jQuery(".outer").children(".widget-static-block").addClass("red");`

Instead of `.find()`:

`jQuery(".outer").find(".widget-static-block").addClass("red");`

> The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a single level down the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

As an alternative, you can use a specific selector to find only the first level down elements.

`jQuery(".outer").find("> .widget-static-block").addClass("red")`

```js
jQuery("p:first").css("background", "limegreen");

jQuery(".panel-heading").addClass("accordion");
jQuery(".list-group").addClass("accordion-panel");

jQuery(".outer").children(".widget-static-block").addClass("red");

var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "block") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.active, .accordion:hover {
  background-color: #ccc; 
}

.accordion-panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.red { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo" class="outer">
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">AAA</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 1
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 2
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 3
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">BBB</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum A
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum B
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum C
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="bar" class="outer">
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">CCC</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 10
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 20
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum 30
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="widget widget-static-block">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
          <h2 style="margin-top: 5px; color: #585858;">DDD</h2>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum AA
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum BB
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="widget widget-static-block">
                Lorem Ipsum CC
            </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you can add an alternative of `jQuery(".outer").find("> .widget-static-block").addClass("red")`, the OP is quite taken with it